# XML To SQL Entity framwork

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, dataset

I have created an `XML Class` and a `SQL Entity Class`.

I need to map the XML to my SQL however I have stumbled into a problem with Arrays which I cannot figure out how to solve.

**First Code**

```
  using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"D:\ArbejdeSEGES\bigdutchman\BigDutchmanXMLReader\BigDutchmanXMLReader\XML\xml-export-01-04-2019 07.00.11.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(export));
                var document = (export)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

                var ventilTable = new Ventil();    

                ventilTable.FarmId = document.farmer.farmid.ToString();

                foreach (var doc in document.device)
                {
                    systemTable.Device = doc.name;

                    foreach (var dialGrp in doc.dialoggroup)
                    {
                        if (dialGrp.id == 1)
                        {
                         ventilTable.Col1 = ????
                         ventilTable.Col2 = ?????
```

**XML**

```
  <export>
  <farmer>
      <farmid>42604</farmid>
  </farmer>
  <device name="FARE-LØBE" online="true">
     <dialoggroup id="1" name="Ventil">
          <field id="1" name="Ventil nr">
              <value index="0">DISP</value>
              <value index="1"></value>
              <value index="2"></value>
              <value index="3"></value>
              <value index="4"></value>
              <value index="5"></value>
              <value index="6"></value>
              <value index="7"></value>
              <value index="8"></value>
              <value index="9"></value>
              <value index="10"></value>
              </field>
               <field id="2" name="1. Mix nr.">
          <value index="0">1</value>
          <value index="1">1</value>
          <value index="2">1</value>
          <value index="3">1</value>
          <value index="4">1</value>
          <value index="5">1</value>
          <value index="6">1</value>
          <value index="7">1</value>
          <value index="8">1</value>
          <value index="9">1</value>
          <value index="10">1</value>
          </field>
```

As you can see im pretty stuck now. Im not sure how to assign all values at once? Should i make a List first? A DataSet?

> Dialoggroup = Table

> Field = Columns

> value = row values

Hope I got everything else please ask :)

Comment: Best way is to design the tables of the database first.  The you can use VS to automatically create the Entity c# classes automaticaly.

Comment: the questions is not about the classes of SQL. I already did those

Answer (score 0):

Use following for serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Export));
            Export export = (Export)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("export")]
    public class Export
    {
        [XmlElement("farmer")]
        public Farmer farmer { get; set; }

        public Device device { get; set; }
 
    }
    public class Farmer
    {
        public int farmid { get; set; }
    }
    public class Device
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public Boolean online { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("dialoggroup")]
        public Dialoggroup dialoggroup { get; set; }
    }
    public class Dialoggroup
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("field")]
        public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    }
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement()]
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }

    }
    public class Value
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int index { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i use this for? I already have an XML class. This is not what i need. I need to figure out how to get the values out

Comment: Does your code work with your xml file?  The code above is tested and correctly parses the xml.

Comment: yes it does - as you can see in my code i can loop through the elements.  I just need to figure out how to loop through field and values at once to insert to datatable or sql entity framework

Comment: The results is a database with tables.  You can always create a database with one table which takes up a lot of space and contains a lot of duplicate information.  So to reduce the size (and remove duplicate info) of a database you create more than one table and link the tables by keys.  So in this case you need to create keys to handle the arrays.